# Apagar todos os Dados ao mandar uma nova Atualização App Android

Tags: android

Fiz umas mudanças no meu app, e preciso apagar todos os dados antigos. O que acontece, é que ao atualizar, os dados antigos ainda ficam armazenados.

A unica solução que achei, e que funcionou, foi mudar o package name. Mas eu não posso fazer isto, pois vou ter que publicar um novo app se mudar o package name

O que funcionou também é se eu for nas configurações e apagar os Dados do App manualmente.

**Pergunta: Existe alguma classe para que quando o usuario atualizar o app, apague todos os dados que tenha no app?**

Comment: dados onde? Shared Preferences? SQLite? Firebase?

Comment: Do Firebase (Informações que ficam no celular armazenadas, não no servidor) mas por garantia preciso apagar tudo que esta armazenado do App, pois mesmo desinstalando, e instalando novamente, os dados antigos continuam la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisará criar este controle na Activity de start do seu app para verificar a versão do app e apagar o que você quiser caso mudar a versão

> Esta comentado no código como o controle deve funcionar.

**Activity LAUNCHER:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Pegar acesso ao SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // Pegar a ultima versão armazenada, se for uma versão anterior a implementação deste
        // controle, vai retornar "0" e fara a limpeza da mesma forma.
        String lastVersion = prefs.getString("APP_VERSION", "0");

        // Pegar a versionName do build.gradle
        String currentVersion = getAppVersion(this);

        // Verificar se mudou a versão
        if (!lastVersion.equals(currentVersion)) {
            // Apagar SharedPrefs
            // Apagar BD
            // Apagar o que for preciso

            // Colocar no Prefs a versão atual para só limpar de novo na proxima att
            prefs.edit().putString("APP_VERSION", currentVersion).apply();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rotina para pegar o versionName do build do app
     * @param context
     * @return version name do arquivo build.gradle
     */
    private String getAppVersion(Context context) {
        String result = "";

        try {
            result = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0)
                    .versionName;
            result = result.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]|-", "");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(context.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.a2sistemas.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2 // Trocar este numero a cada att
        versionName "2.0" // Trocar este numero a cada att
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Comment: Fui testar aqui, e esta dando erro no if (!lastVersion.equals. Aparece "Can not resolve "equals", voce sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Você criou a variável lasVersion como String ? o equal é um método da classe String para comprar os valores.